# CSS Issue - Characters going underneath password show/hide icon

Tags: css

```js
const forms = document.querySelector(".forms"),
    pwShowHide = document.querySelectorAll(".eye-icon"),
    links = document.querySelectorAll(".link");

    pwShowHide.forEach(eyeIcon => {eyeIcon.addEventListener("click",() => 
        {let pwFields = eyeIcon.parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll(".password");

        pwFields.forEach(password => {
            if(password.type === "password"){
                password.type = "text";
                eyeIcon.classList.replace("bx-hide","bx-show");
                return;
            }
            password.type = "password";
            eyeIcon.classList.replace("bx-show","bx-hide");
        })
    })
})
```

```css
/* Font */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@300;400;600&display=swap');

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}

.container{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.form{
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 430px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
}
.form.signup{
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
header{
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
}
form{
  margin-top: 30px;
}
form a{
  color:#2b2b2b;
  text-decoration: none;
}
form a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
form .field{
  height: 50px;
  width: 340px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.field input,
.field button{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;

}
.field button{
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.field input{
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  /* Added code */
  padding:4px 70px 4px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.eye-icon{
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #8b8b8b;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}
.form-link{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.form-link span,
.form-link a{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Page Title -->
        <title>Login - LNEM</title>
    
        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    
        <!-- Icon CSS -->
        <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="container forms">
            <div class="form-content">
                <header>Login</header>

                <form action="#">
                    <div class="field input-field">
                        <!-- Email Address -->
                        <input type="text" class="login-input" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                    </div>

                    <div class="field input-field">
                        <input type="password" class="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                        <i class='bx bx-hide eye-icon'></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-link">
                        <a href="forgot_password.html" class="forgot-pass">Forgot Password?</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field button-field">
                        <button>Sign In</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-link">
                        <span>Don't have an account? <a href="register.html" class="signup-link">Create Account</a></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- Javascript -->
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Im relatively new to CSS coding and whilst creating a login/register form for my coursework i noticed that within the password input field, the characters are appearing underneath the show/hide icon as shown below
is there any way to fix this?

I have visited a couple threads on this site and have found half the problem where padding was added, it has solved half the problem since it stops the vertical line ("|" <-- this thing) from going over the icon but once I show the password some characters still appear underneath the icon

Comment: Please provide the ability to run your code and reproduce the problem using the snippets editor https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers

Comment: @Taras I've updated the post so you can now see the full form

Comment: Both examples work fine for me. But the first one has more padding to the right. Try checking it in incognito browser mode to rule out any issues with extensions.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems to work for me when I change padding-right, but it's also possible that some css directives weren't applied because some html might have been missing.

```css
/* Font */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@300;400;600&display=swap');

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}
.field{
  height: 50px;
  width: 340px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.field input,
.field button{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;

}
.field button{
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.field input{
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  /* Added code */
  padding:4px 40px 4px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.eye-icon{
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #8b8b8b;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<div class="field input-field">
  <input type="password" class="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  <i class='bx bx-hide eye-icon'></i>
</div>
```